# Why is Canny different in Python/OpenCV and OpenCV.JS?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, opencv

I am developing a [React web app](https://www.arflowarts.com). This app was developed in Python3 with OpenCV4, and now I am implementing it in React with [OpenCV.JS](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/d10/tutorial_js_root.html). One of the features is [Canny Edge Detection](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/de1/tutorial_js_canny.html). Canny edge detection works differently in Python and Javascript.

This is the code that I used in the Python3 version:

```
_, img = cap.read()
canny = cv2.Canny(img, h,s)
```

This is the code that I used in the [React OpenCV.JS version](https://github.com/ianboru/juggle-tracker-js):

```
cv.cvtColor(srcMat, srcMat, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY, 0);
cv.Canny(srcMat, canny, store.cannyMinVal, store.cannyMaxVal);
```

The results are different, and the Python3 version results are better. This gif shows the Python results:
[image: python gif]

This gif shows the OpenCV.JS results:

[image: opencv.js results]

This image compares the two:

[image: compare Python and OpenCV.JS]

Why am I getting different results in my React and Python versions?
Why do I have to convert the source image to grayscale in the OpenCV.JS version?

Comment: Are you sure it is `COLOR_RGB2GRAY` and not `COLOR_BGR2GRAY`? Also, I think the input of canny is always a greyscale image, could it be that it is only taking the first channel of the BGR image in the python code?

Comment: @api55 I tried 'RGB' and 'BGR' in the reactjs version. There was no difference. I also tried converting the image to gray in the Python version. The Canny image was slightly worse. The Python version works better when I use the three channel image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, I use

```
capture = cv.cvtColor(original_image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

However, in OpenCV JS, the color space of source is different. It is RGB instead of BGR.

```
 cv.cvtColor(original_image, capture, cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY, 0);
```